# Prove that DE || BC

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let M be the midpoint of side BC in triangle ABC.  The angle bisector of BMA intersects AB in D, while the angle bisector of CMA intersects AC in E.  How can i prove that DE||BC?  I drew out the triangle and all the bisectors and points but I have no idea where to start.  I was thinking maybe I can prove CE=MD and then by parallelogram DE||BC?  I have no idea how to go about this though. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the angle bisector theorem and similar triangles to prove equality of distances. From there, you are right about the parallelogram.
One thing though is I know this statement is true for medians, but might be false for angle bisectors.